# How to shift figlet output

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, console, ascii-art

I need to shift a FIGlet output (for example to the center of terminal). How can i do this? 
I tried

```
(tput sc ; tput cup 23 45 ; figlet text; tput rc)
```

but it doesn't work.

It isn't obligatory to use figlet, it is possible to use any program which transforms the text to "ascii art".

thanks!

**Upd1:** sorry, guys. "centering" was just an example. Generally it is necessary for me to shift this text for a fixed rows and cols, like

```
tput cup 10 10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Centering is easy:

```
figlet -w $(tput cols) -c hello
```

- the `-c` mean *center*
- the `-w num` sets the line width for the `figlet`
- the `tput cols` returns the columns of the current terminal

In the general, you can use the `-w` for setting the `line width` to some number, let say `40` and the use the `-c` and you will get the text shifted...

```
$ figlet -w 30  -c hello
     _          _ _       
    | |__   ___| | | ___  
    | '_ \ / _ \ | |/ _ \ 
    | | | |  __/ | | (_) |
    |_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/ 

$ figlet -w 50  -c hello
               _          _ _       
              | |__   ___| | | ___  
              | '_ \ / _ \ | |/ _ \ 
              | | | |  __/ | | (_) |
              |_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/
```

Also, you can shift the output by adding some spaces to the start, for example by `sed`

```
figlet hello | sed 's/^/               /'
```

or perl

```
figlet hello | perl -nle 'print " " x 30 . $_'
```

Comment: Figlet actually has this built in with `-t` so you can simply write `figlet -tc hello`

Comment: @Cody the `-t` just sets the output `width` to _"terminal width"_.  Also, on some installations it not works and just prints error like: _"-t" is disabled, since ioctl is not fully implemented_. The OP asked for the output __shifting__ and the `-t` is definitely isn't the right solution. Read: [man figlet](http://www.figlet.org/figlet-man.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
~$ echo $'\r\r\r\r\r\r'; figlet '                           text'

                            _            _   
                           | |_ _____  _| |_ 
                           | __/ _ \ \/ / __|
                           | ||  __/>  <| |_ 
                            \__\___/_/\_\\__|

~$
```